# Operation on a large array of elements

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am wondering how to go faster than a loop to apply an operation on a full array of objects...

```
template <class T>
inline
void operate(T &_this)
        
     { /* do something with _this */ }
```

I obviously did my first code like :

```
template <class T>
void loop(const size_t_total, T *_array)
    
     { for(unsigned _cursor(0); _cursor < _total; _cursor++)
          { T *_t(_array + _cursor); 
            ::operate<T>(*_t);
           }
     }
```

Then I decided to turn loop() into a Thread...

So I modified loop() function to iterate() function and added an apply() function to loop using a slice variable, so that I could interrupt the Thread and manage the growing calling stack...

```
template <class T>
inline
void iterate(const size_t &_total, T *_these, void (*_that)(T &))
    
     { if(_these != 0)
         { if(_total > 1)
             ::iterate<T>(_total - 1, _these + 1, _that);
    
           _that(*_these);
         }
     }
    
template <class T, size_t SLICE = 1024>
inline
void apply(const size_t &_total, T *_these, void (*_that)(T &))
    
     { if(_total > 0)
          { const bool _recurse(_total > SLICE);
    
            if(_recurse == true)
              ::apply<T>(SLICE, _total - SLICE, _these + SLICE, _that);
    
            ::iterate<T>((_recurse == true) ? SLICE : _total, _these, _that);
          }
      }
```

Everything is fine...

I assume that, because of the positions of the recursive calls within apply() and iterate(), the speed for processing the whole array should be largely increased in front of using the simple loop() function...

I just wonder if the compiler (Borland C++ Builder 5) will do the perfect job (I mean shadowing the operate() and scope the parameters as every elements of the array) or if I am missing something...

But is it right ?

Comment: Given the fact that Borland C++ a prehistoric compiler that was written back when dinosaurs roamed the earth, I doubt that much hope can be placed into any compiler-based optimizations.

Comment: Do you think that for such operation a new compiler could do that ? Which one ? I mean : is there an assembly instruction with the new processors, that combines a function and an array so that it will "flash" the operation ?

Comment: Or better question : should I create as many subthreads as slicing requires, and will it be the fastest execution ?

Comment: The only way to know whether a given compiler will perform the given optimization is to try it, and see it what happens. C++ allows, but does not require, C++ compilers to perform any optimization that has no observable effects. It is true that some reasonable guesses can be made about typical results from modern C++ compilers, like gcc and clang; however the ultimate answer is: you have to try it yourself, to determine the extent of the compiler's optimizations.

Comment: The two codes are not equivalent. The calback will not be optimized in the second one (unless the whole code is inlined which is very unlikely with threads on the way or if you use PGO possibly combined with LTO which is pretty uncommon) and it is not clear why do you use recursion (which generally add overhead and often prevent inlining)...

Comment: The only function that's not inlined is operate() ... but apply() and iterate() are inlined... The SLICE parameter is then used to prevent a growing stack call within the thread... recursion is used to tell the compiler that the scope to "operate()" is from last to first of the array...

Comment: About the equivalence of the 2 codes : sure the first starts with first element and scopes to the last... but the second is slightly different because it supports a slicing...

Comment: are you stuck with Borland C++ compiler? Because if not, in C++17 you should be able to use parallel algorithms (like std::for_each) by passing additional ExecutionPolicy argument.

Comment: Aware about std:for_each but i have compatibility dues about using that 32 & 16 bits compiler

Comment: Thanks to all I decided to use a thread strategy combined with a slicing of my array... Threads are created and started to poll a scope within the array and stop at termination or found... I then manage within a waiting loop if all have finished...